# Rust polars: IntoSeries trait is not implemented for &Series

Tags: dataframe, rust, series, traits, rust-cargo

I am new to Rust, so I am sorry if this question may sound stupid. I am trying to dig into `polars` to learn more how to work with data frames and series in Rust.
I am now trying to read a dataframe, extract a column, drop that column from the dataframe and re-add the column back to the dataframe:

```
use polars::prelude::*;
use polars::frame::DataFrame;
use polars::series::IntoSeries;

fn main() {
    // 1. read an input csv file and create a dataframe.             
    // 2. get a dataframe column 
    let series_column = df.column("COLUMN_NAME").unwrap(); 
    // 3. drop this column 
    df.drop_in_place("COLUMN_NAME"); 
    // 4. re-insert that column at index 0
    let new_df = df.insert_at_idx(0, series_column);
```

Although I tried many ways I always have this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&Series: IntoSeries` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:78:36
   |
78 |     let new_df = df.insert_at_idx(0, series_column);
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `IntoSeries` is not implemented for `&Series`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <Series as IntoSeries>
}
```

Looking at the `help` line it seems there is a Trait confusion, but I can't get how to solve this issue.
Where am I wrong?
Thanks

Comment: The type of `series_column` is `&Series`, but `IntoSeries` is implemented for `Series` (note the ampersand).

Comment: Thanks @so61pi
I see. So, how could I extract a column and re-insert in a dataframe then?

Comment: I think since you already use `drop_in_place`, you can get its result, which is `Result<Series, PolarsError>`, then use the `Series` to insert.

Comment: You're right!  
It works now :) 
Thanks for your help